# Possible to change DCOM port for HP ALM/UFT?

Tags: hp-uft, dcom

I am trying to integration HP ALM with UFT, so ALM can execute UFT test. However the two products are installed in different network zone. The security has concern to open low port number (those below 1024). Thus would it be possible to change DCOM to use a different port for ALM and UFT to talk to each other? Or is there workaround for this?